# Using webpack to build a angular2+systemjs project 404 templates error

Tags: angular, build, webpack, systemjs

I'd like to configure webpack just to build my project (at least for now) and in the meantime keep systemjs working (the development of this project is started with systemjs).

Now, I tried three days ago to insert webpack in my project, I basically used everything I found here (didn't touch anything about webpack config) https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html

I switched the tsconfig.json to **commonjs**, I launched the **npm run build** command you can find in the link and I retouched the dist/index.html to make it fully compatible (removing some original systemjs stuff).
But no matter what, I'm full of **404 error** because zone.js can't find my components' template BUT if I move all the templates where he wants to, it works perfectly.

I searched this thing and it's due to webpack that needs to get the template with the require but the **angular2-template-loader** is in there on purpose, is it not working? What should I do to fix this?

This is the main webpack configuration (named in the angular guide as webpack.common.js):

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'app': './src/main.ts'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
        loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap')
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loader: 'raw'
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

Hoping for help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue, and as a temporary solution I'm copying over the css and html files using the **copy-webpack-plugin**.

To do this add the CopyWebpackPlugin to the *devDependencies* in the **package.json** file:

```
"copy-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.3",
```

Then in your **webpack.common.js** file add the *require* statement at the top:

```
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
```

And then you use it in your *plugins* section of your **webpack.common.js** file:

```
 plugins: [
  new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      { from: 'src/*.html', to: './' }
  ]),
  new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      { from: 'src/*.css', to: './' }
  ])
]
```

Comment: I was doing it too but actually I left this way and started to use angular-cli. I didn't want a ready-and-go package but since I need a very fast way to enter in production I couldn't lose any more time.
Thank you for your answer anyway